# Quebra de linha não funciona em arquivo

Tags: c

Pego os elementos de uma lista mas na hora de salvar ele nao salva com quebra de linha salva tudo na mesma linha.

```
fprintf(arquivo, "%s\n", p->infoLinha);
```

Comment: Ele está salvando tudo na mesma linha, ou o seu editor de texto precisa que você use o `\r\n` para separar as linhas? Por exemplo, se você abrir o arquivo gerado no wordpad (em vez de notepad), você vê as linhas separadas?

Comment: Obrigado precisava do \r\n

Answer (score 4):

Tens de abrir o arquivo em modo texto

```
arquivo = fopen(nome_arquivo, "w"); // modo sem "b"
fprintf(arquivo, "%s\n", info);
```

Se, mesmo assim, o `'\n'` nao for convertido para a quebra de linha normal para o teu SO especifico, abre o arquivo em modo binario e usa `"\r\n"`

```
arquivo = fopen(nome_arquivo, "wb"); // modo com "b"
fprintf(arquivo, "%s\r\n", info);
```

*Nota que a primeira opção faz o programa funcionar correctamente em todos os ambientes (Windows, Linux, Mac, controlador de elevador, space shuttle, ...); a segunda opção faz o programa gerar ficheiros Windows independentemente do ambiente em que é executado.

Se for necessário gerar um ficheiro Windows em Linux, a melhor maneira é criar o ficheiro em modo Linux e convertê-lo para modo Windows durante o processo de transferênica (o FTP pode fazer isso automaticamente, por exemplo)*

Answer (score 0):

Acrescentei o \r e funcionou

```
fprintf(arquivo, "%s\r\n", p->infoLinha);
```